# AJAX uploads issue in Django app

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have followed the tutorial posted [here](http://kuhlit.blogspot.com/2010/12/ajax-uploads-in-django-with-little-help.html?showComment=1298110680880#c941820233059113774) in order to get AJAX file uploads on my Django app. The thing is that it doesn't work, and the closest I could get to the issue is finding out that the **save_upload()** method raises the following exception: **'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'read'**. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I figured out that this is only works in Django 1.3. Any ideeas on how to make it work in Django 1.2?

Comment: What is the uploaded argument that you're passing to save_upload()?

Comment: I'd love to know if there's been any movement on this.  Were you saying that the WSGIRequest was OK being subject to read() in Django 1.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have gotten to the bottom of your problem.

1) You are trying to run .read() on a request object, which is not allowed.  Instead, you need to run it on request.raw_post_data.

2) Before you can run .read(), which takes a file-like object, you need to convert it from a str to a file-like object.

Try this:

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write(request.raw_post_data)
```

...now you'll be able to run output.read() and get the data you want.

```
        #loop through, writing more of the file each time
        file_so_far = output.read( 1024 ) #Get ready....
        while file_so_far: #..get set...
          dest.write( file_so_far ) #Go.
          file_so_far = output.read( 1024
```